# Add custom field in shipping address form of Checkout for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, xml

Below I have a shipping address form of checkout page and I would like to add another field `(P.O. Box)` in this form. I tried to look it up every forums and most of the answers were based on overriding.

`Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`. 
I checked `app/code/company/Checkout/etc/di.xml` but wasn't referencing `layoutprocessor`.

I am still confused from where this form is getting values from `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface` or `Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

[image]

how can I add custom field to this form?

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting today.  Bit of trial and error but managed to add PO box to checkout

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Postbox

Too much code to summarise here really.  It was a lot more involved process than I thought it would be.

This tutorial helped a lot

https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/